# FFMPEG - PNG Overlay - Fade In / Out - Start & End of video + Combine Videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, overlay

Hoping someone can help me with this.

I'm looking to automate some editing tasks.

I want to write an FFMPEG command that will do the following. Input is VIDEO.MP4

- Add a 1 second fade in and out to VIDEO.MP4
- Fade in and out a PNG overlay at 5 seconds (duration 30 seconds) and also the last 30 seconds of VIDEO.MP4.
- Output the video (combined INTRO.MP4 + VIDEO.MP4 (with watermarks and fades) + ENDING.MP4)

Is this possible within FFMPEG alone? I'm willing to use multiple command-line options if available.